# How can I condense a 'for x in range' statement within a 'if' 'elif' statement within a 'while' statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that makes a math table and I feel has the possibility to be reduced as I have three of the same codes repeated but with only slightly different solutions for each of the if/elif statements.

```
num=10
x=str(input("Enter Math Operation (+, -, *): "))
while (x != "+" and x != "-" and x != "*"):
    x=str(input("\tEnter Math Operation: "))
    if x=="+":
        for table in range(1,11):
            print(str(num),str(x),table,"=",num+table) 
    elif x=="-":
       for table in range(1,11):
            print(str(num),str(x),table,"=",num-table) 
    elif x=="*":
       for table in range(1,11):
            print(str(num),str(x),table,"=",num*table)
```

Please tell me how this code can be condensed.

Comment: You could make one for-loop containing the if's, but it would be slower with large tables. You could use exec with the right operator as a string, but it would be slow and vulnerable. You could pass an add, subtract etc. function to a loop iterating the list, but it would be overkill and slower. In short, I think the amount of code dupplication here is acceptable. DRY, but not too DRY...

Answer (score 6):

You would typically do something like this:

- Store the operator as a function in a variable
- Use a dictionary to look up operators
- Use `.format()` instead of putting lots of string pieces together
- Don't use `str()` if the argument is already a string

Here is what that looks like:

```
import operator
x = 10
operators = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
}
while True:
    op_name = input('Enter Math Operation ({}): '.format(', '.join(operators)))
    op_func = operators.get(op_name)
    if op_func is not None:
        break
for y in range(1, 11):
    print('{} {} {} = {}'.format(x, op_name, y, op_func(x, y)))
```

Comment: Gosh, this is so much better quality than some of the earlier answers (and I am the author of one)!  It's the difference between someone who knows python, and someone who is a real expert.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookup table to store the different functions

```
num=10
x=str(input("Enter Math Operation (+, -, *): "))
while (x != "+" and x != "-" and x != "*"):
    x=str(input("\tEnter Math Operation: "))
ops = {
    '+': lambda x, y: x+y,
    '-': lambda x, y: x-y,
    '*': lambda x, y: x*y}

fn = ops[x]
for table in range(1,11):
    print(str(num),str(x),table,"=",fn(num,table))
```

Comment: He could, but would you do that in this simple case?

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I might not, but I hope a code reviewer would call me out on the fact I had repeated two lines of code three times - which is enough to trigger DRY to my mind.  I'd certainly fix it if they did.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine - the table rather than the elif chain is much more elegant.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge 1.  The expensive bit is the "print".  2.  Performance is not an issue until measurement tells you it is (clarity is more important than premature optimization.  3.  If performance *really* is an issue, python is probably the wrong language for this bit.

Comment: I departed from the assumption that thoses lists might as well contain a million items... And I agree that clarity is more important than premature optimization. Only I think the use of a table in this trivial case isn't serving clarity. If the number of operators would expand, by the way, I'd choose the table solution. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first class objects in python.  Assign the right function to a variable, and then use it.

```
num=10
x=str(input("Enter Math Operation (+, -, *): "))
# Read operation
while (x != "+" and x != "-" and x != "*"):
    x=str(input("\tEnter Math Operation: "))
# Select appropriate function
if x=="+":
    op = lambda x, y : x + y
elif x=="-":
    op = lambda x, y : x - y
elif x=="*":
    op = lambda x, y : x * y

# Use function
for table in range(1,11):
    val = op(num, table)
    print(str(num), str(x),table,"=", val)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# building a math table-machine

Y = int(input('ENTER A VALUE TO GET A TABLE: '))   # Type a multiplier


B = int()      # Taking B and x as an integer, B is our multiplicand 
x = int()      # x is our product (Y multiplies with B to give x)

while Y <= 10 and B <= 10 and x <= 100:       # choose length and width of the table you want.

    print(f'{Y} times {B} is {x}')    # formatting 
    x += Y     # Adding Y(multiplier) with x(product) resulting in forming a table. 
    B += 1      # loop completed! ready to work.

print('made your homework easy chump!')
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem